# Suggest link to add to contacts for email recipients

Tags: email, html-email

I am trying to avoid going into the spam folder when I send an email to users on my website.
Mainly I need them to activate their newly registered account and if it's in the spam folder, they most likely will never activate it.

I noticed that for the most part, it's Hotmail that blocks my emails.
I read a lot that the more people mark it as not-spam, and if they add the email to their contacts, that why it increases the chances of not going to spam folders in the future.

Is there a way to offer a link for "add this email to your contacts" in the html body of the email?

Also, what can I do to not get to the spam in general? I tried stripping all the html and just send plain text but still went to spam...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent your emails from going to spam can entail optimizing a number of things such as

1. Text of the email (even if it's plain text.. spammy/salesy wording will still trigger spam
2. The domain in which your sending the email from
3. Whether or not your sending domain is authenticated (e.g. SPF, DKIM)
4. Checking that your not on spam lists

What people usually do is create a link to a page which provides step by step instructions on how users can whitelist the sender in various email clients and providers.

This website will actually auto-generate the instructions page for you:  http://www.emaildeliveryjedi.com/email-whitelist.php

---

Mailchimp offers a solution which allows you to add an 'Add-to-Address-Book' link to your campaigns but it's not very broadly compatible with all clients.  What they're doing is embedded hcard microdata.

### Further:

- [Mailchimp Add-to-Address-Book Links](http://blog.mailchimp.com/add-to-address-book-link-for-email-campaigns/)
- [hCard](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/hcard)

Comment: The instruction generator is cool, the only problem is that the user who receives my email will get it into his junk folder, therefore, this instructions will never be seen.. I am using PHPmailer and SPF with godaddy, and i simply change the long email with my server's ip in it to support@example.com. Is there a list for "spammy" words that trigger the email to be marked as spam?

Comment: there is no definite 'list' but here's a good substitute to get started with..  spend some time on Google and you can get lost for days reading about various spam filters, algorithms, etc.. http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/30684/The-Ultimate-List-of-Email-SPAM-Trigger-Words.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend sending a test email to http://isnotspam.com/

They run a SpamAssassin test (and a few others) on the email and give you an output, which is a good metric to judge most spam filters by.

Another thing to look out for is that GMail's doesn't like when you mention money at all, especially large amounts.